# Assign multiple users to business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, bulk, sfmc-business-unit

Having more than 500 users and 170 child business units in my org, I'd like to handle assigning a number of existing users to an existing business unit easily.

In *Setup / Users / Import* the Bulk User Update instructions tells me to create a .csv file with this user information:
**name*, username*, password*, reply email address*, notification email address*, enabled*, role external keys (*Required Field)**

Can I assign users to a business unit this way by adding a **business unit field** to the .csv file, or should I go for the Bulk Business Unit update option in *Setup / Business Units / Import* instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer to this question is actually straightforward:
**No, a business unit field can not be added to the .csv.**
The .csv can only be filled in as is it available in Setup / Users / Import

What this functionality actually does is that it assigns users in that .csv to the business unit in which the functionality is accessed.

This not only assigns that business unit to the users, but also adds that business unit as the default business unit for the users. If the users had an association to another business unit before the update, that association would be removed.

Last thing to mention is that the password field is a required field in the .csv for this functionality. In my case, trying to assign a new business unit to existing users, this would complicate things as I would have no idea of the passwords for the users I'm trying update by assigning them to an existing business unit.

I have not been able to find any documentation for this, so everything learned about this comes from cases created in the Help and Training Portal.

Answer (score -1):

As per the documentation, there is no business unit related field that can be utilized in an import file.

You can try the SSJS core library function which can be used to do this task easily. Please refer the doc -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_accountUserAdd.htm

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @Akash even though this is unavailable to me in my existing scenario, it's nice to know of this for future cases :)